# How to prove a number is in the A002620 sequence.

Tags: matrices, functions, nonnegative-matrices

I am working on a project in PHP where I generate a number and want to see if said number is part of the A002620 sequence. I've started by looking at https://oeis.org/A002620 "Quarter-squares: floor(n/2)*ceiling(n/2). Equivalently, floor(n^2/4)."

I am confused how to implement, If I do `floor(n^2/4)` it proves nothing (below). I am a developer with basic Math so if someone could explain the process.

```
<?php
  $start_num = 9;
  $sum = floor($start_num**2/4);             
  echo $sum;
  //result 20
?>
```

Comment: $\left\lfloor\frac{n^2}{4}\right\rfloor=x$, $x\le\frac{n^2}{4}< x+1$, $4x\le n^2< 4x+4$ so if `ceil((4*x)**0.5)==floor((4*(x+1))**0.5)` then $x$ is in the sequence unless `floor((4*(x+1))**0.5)**2==4*(x+1)`.  [testing, python](https://tio.run/##LcrNCsIwDADgu08Rb0mE0fkDMuiTiIeiq8vYmhJ6qE9fcez8fflbJk2Xe7bWZM1qBdZQpkM2SQUfFaIaVJAEFtJnxN45RyBxW91rlAXxypWYXXcj73Ee/EZxUbW/YT31tDtBSG@Ymc9Hv8uTWvsB)

Comment: Could the above formula also tell you the grid size e.g. if x is 6 you get 3,2 as the grid?

Comment: Not sure I get you about a 'grid'? Does the below answer help?

Answer (score 1):

At the given A002620 you find the following explicit formula for $a(n)$:
$$a(n)={1\over8}\bigl(2n^2-1+(-1)^n\bigr)\qquad(n\geq0)\ .\tag{1}$$
This leads to the sequence
$$0, 0, 1, 2, 4, 6, 9, 12, 16, 20, 25, 30, 36, 42, 49, 56, 64, 72, 81, \
90, 100 \ldots$$
When the  number $a(n)=:a$ is given  we immediately obtain from $(1)$ that
$$n^2=4a+{1-(-1)^n\over2}\ .\tag{2}$$
Now it seems that you have arbitrary numbers $N\in{\mathbb N}$ and want to know whether this $N$ is an $a(n)$. From $(2)$ we can deduce the following:

- If $\sqrt{N}$ is integer then $N=a(n)$ for the even $n=2\sqrt{N}$.
- If $\sqrt{4N+1}$ is integer then $N=a(n)$ for the odd $n=\sqrt{4N+1}$.